# how to add login and logout in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I am very new to php, i need help adding a login and logout button. If the user is already logged in, I want the login to be hidden.And if the user is logged out, I want the logout to be hidden. The login/logout button should be in html and php. Please and thank you

Here are the scripts I’m using

Here is the login/logout buttons I tried using :

```
            <a href="/login-user.php" class="navbar-signin">
              <span>login</span>
              <ion-icon name="log-in-outline"></ion-icon>
              <span> <?php echo $fetch_info['name'] ?> </span>
            </a>  
            <a href="/logout-user.php" class="navbar-signin">
              <span>Log out</span>
              <ion-icon name="log-in-outline"></ion-icon>
              <span> <?php echo $fetch_info['name'] ?> </span>
            </a>
```

Here is the code i use for my index.php:

```
<?php require_once "controllerUserData.php"; ?>
<?php $email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
if($email != false && $password != false){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
    $run_Sql = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($run_Sql){
        $fetch_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_Sql);
        $status = $fetch_info['status'];
        $code = $fetch_info['code'];
        if($status == "verified"){
            if($code != 0){
                header('Location: reset-code.php');
            }
        }else{
            header('Location: user-otp.php');
        }
    }
}else{
    header('Location:  ');
}
?>
```

Controller user data:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require "connection.php";
$email = "";
$name = "";
$errors = array();

//if user signup button
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
    if($password !== $cpassword){
        $errors['password'] = "Confirm password not matched!";
    }
    $email_check = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $email_check);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        $errors['email'] = "Email that you have entered is already exist!";
    }
    if(count($errors) === 0){
        $encpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $code = rand(999999, 111111);
        $status = "notverified";
        $insert_data = "INSERT INTO usertable (name, email, password, code, status)
                        values('$name', '$email', '$encpass', '$code', '$status')";
        $data_check = mysqli_query($con, $insert_data);
        if($data_check){
            $subject = "Email Verification Code";
            $message = "Your verification code is $code";
            $sender = "From: email";
            if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $sender)){
                $info = "We've sent a verification code to your email - $email";
                $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                header('location: user-otp.php');
                exit();
            }else{
                $errors['otp-error'] = "Failed while sending code!";
            }
        }else{
            $errors['db-error'] = "Failed while inserting data into database!";
        }
    }

}
    //if user click verification code submit button
    if(isset($_POST['check'])){
        $_SESSION['info'] = "";
        $otp_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['otp']);
        $check_code = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE code = $otp_code";
        $code_res = mysqli_query($con, $check_code);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($code_res) > 0){
            $fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code_res);
            $fetch_code = $fetch_data['code'];
            $email = $fetch_data['email'];
            $code = 0;
            $status = 'verified';
            $update_otp = "UPDATE usertable SET code = $code, status = '$status' WHERE code = $fetch_code";
            $update_res = mysqli_query($con, $update_otp);
            if($update_res){
                $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                header('location: index.php');
                exit();
            }else{
                $errors['otp-error'] = "Failed while updating code!";
            }
        }else{
            $errors['otp-error'] = "You've entered incorrect code!";
        }
    }

    //if user click login button
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
        $check_email = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $check_email);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
            $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $fetch_pass = $fetch['password'];
            if(password_verify($password, $fetch_pass)){
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $status = $fetch['status'];
                if($status == 'verified'){
                  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                  $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                    header('location: index.php');
                }else{
                    $info = "It's look like you haven't still verify your email - $email";
                    $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
                    header('location: user-otp.php');
                }
            }else{
                $errors['email'] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            }
        }else{
            $errors['email'] = "It's look like you're not yet a member! Click on the bottom link to signup.";
        }
    }

    //if user click continue button in forgot password form
    if(isset($_POST['check-email'])){
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $check_email = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email='$email'";
        $run_sql = mysqli_query($con, $check_email);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_sql) > 0){
            $code = rand(999999, 111111);
            $insert_code = "UPDATE usertable SET code = $code WHERE email = '$email'";
            $run_query =  mysqli_query($con, $insert_code);
            if($run_query){
                $subject = "Password Reset Code";
                $message = "Your password reset code is $code";
                $sender = "From: email";
                if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $sender)){
                    $info = "We've sent a passwrod reset otp to your email - $email";
                    $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    header('location: reset-code.php');
                    exit();
                }else{
                    $errors['otp-error'] = "Failed while sending code!";
                }
            }else{
                $errors['db-error'] = "Something went wrong!";
            }
        }else{
            $errors['email'] = "This email address does not exist!";
        }
    }

    //if user click check reset otp button
    if(isset($_POST['check-reset-otp'])){
        $_SESSION['info'] = "";
        $otp_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['otp']);
        $check_code = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE code = $otp_code";
        $code_res = mysqli_query($con, $check_code);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($code_res) > 0){
            $fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code_res);
            $email = $fetch_data['email'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $info = "Please create a new password that you don't use on any other site.";
            $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
            header('location: new-password.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            $errors['otp-error'] = "You've entered incorrect code!";
        }
    }

    //if user click change password button
    if(isset($_POST['change-password'])){
        $_SESSION['info'] = "";
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
        $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
        if($password !== $cpassword){
            $errors['password'] = "Confirm password not matched!";
        }else{
            $code = 0;
            $email = $_SESSION['email']; //getting this email using session
            $encpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $update_pass = "UPDATE usertable SET code = $code, password = '$encpass' WHERE email = '$email'";
            $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $update_pass);
            if($run_query){
                $info = "Your password changed. Now you can login with your new password.";
                $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
                header('Location: password-changed.php');
            }else{
                $errors['db-error'] = "Failed to change your password!";
            }
        }
    }
    
   //if login now button click
    if(isset($_POST['login-now'])){
        header('Location: login-user.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Just do with `if-else` statement as your done in many other code blocks :)

Comment: FYI: There is no need to store the password in the session variable

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && !empty($_SESSION['email'])) {?>
      <a href="/logout-user.php" class="navbar-signin">
         <span>Log out</span>
         <ion-icon name="log-in-outline"></ion-icon>
         <span> <?php echo $fetch_info['name'] ?> </span>
      </a>

<?php } else {?>
     <a href="/login-user.php" class="navbar-signin">
       <span>login</span>
       <ion-icon name="log-in-outline"></ion-icon>
       <span> <?php echo $fetch_info['name'] ?> </span>
     </a>
<?php }?>
```